# unable to configure nor able to uninstall virtual box

Tags: software-uninstall, configure

I have installed virtual box from app manager and installed it on ubuntu 18. But i was uble to run any program on virtual box since it was giving a error.

**Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)**

To solve this problem i tried to reinstall it. During re-installation program was stuck at a point[for which i have not taken screen shot]. I waited for 5 to 10 minutes for program to finish. But it doesn't so i stopped it forcefully. After that whenever i am trying to uninstall or configure this virtual box i am getting stuck at this point shown in picture. Program is not going future [program is stuck hear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTp5g.png). What to do??

Comment: Yes. But no result . It is not getting installed at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this solution  it worked for me
1. sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
2. From package manager unistall that broken software 
3. sudo dpkg --configure -a

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

1) $sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms

2) $sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms

3) $sudo modprobe vboxdrv

4) $sudo modprobe vboxnetflt

Let me know if it works for you please!

Comment: Thank for reply @sylla.  It is not working. When i typed first step it is showing following error **E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.**

Comment: Did you run  'sudo dpkg --configure -a'   to fix the error?

Comment: That is what  the main problem. Which i have explained in brief with picture. Due this problem some other software are not getting installed or removed. It is repeatedly giving same error that is **to configure**..